# Move JS calculation result from Input field to JS within php tags

Tags: javascript, php

This is for an offline client side js calculation script.  I am aware php is server side.

I am a newbie I am trying to get the result of a calulation into php tags.
The whole script works fine but I want to move the result from being in an Input field and instead into php tags.  Many thanks.

The script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rowcount-btn").click(function(){ 

    var sum = 0;
    $('.rowcount').each(function() {
        if($(this).val()!="")
         {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
         }

    });
         // result displayed in this input field
          $("#total").val(sum);

       // I added this, but  it does not work. Its shows you what I am trying to achieve
       result = " $("#total").val(sum)";
         
});
});


</script>
```

I  want the result from above script to be displayed in the script below.  so I can move the result to where I want it .

```
<?php echo '<script>document.write(result)</script>';?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is executed on server-side before JavaScript is executed on the client-side.

The only way to get results of JavaScript calculation back to PHP server is to make a network request to the server, for example using [`jQuery.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

However, I suppose you only need to output the result of calculation anywhere on the page, so here's how to do it:

- add empty HTML tag with unique ID to the page `<div id="result-output"></div>`
- update JavaScript code to output calculation result into that HTML tag

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#rowcount-btn").click(function(){ 

    var sum = 0;
    $('.rowcount').each(function() {
        if($(this).val()!="")
         {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
         }

    });
    // result displayed in HTML tag
    $("#result-output").html(sum);
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Vitalii This does help me !!  and it is aa good solution. Yes  this is for an offline client side  calculation. The reason for me wanting  the output within php tags is becuase i want to  use a php query like if  the result is empty ( no found records to count) then  put a zero  and not leave the result empty

Comment: Thank you Vitalii  this has pointed me in the right direction!   I reaslise I don't need the php tags , but use your method